# Freezing First Column and Header, but they are not appearing now

Tags: javascript, html, css

I searched through the forum and found how to get this to work.  Well when I put it to work with my data, the first column and header disappear, but seems to scroll like I want it.  Here is the fiddle for what I have so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/p9PeK/7/

This is the HTML:

```
<div class='q1'><div class='container'></div></div>
<div class='q2'><div class='container'></div></div>
<div class='q3'><div class='container'></div></div>
<div class='q4'>
    <div id='container'>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class='firstCol'>Julian Date</td>
                    <td class='records'>Records</td>
                    <td class='deals'>Deals</td>
                    <td class='cpo'>CPO</td>
                    <td class='state'>AL Rec</td>
                    <td class='state'>AL Sold</td>
                    <td class='state'>AK Rec</td>
                    <td class='state'>AK Sold</td>
                    <td class='state'>AZ Rec</td>
                    <td class='state'>AZ Sold</td>
                    <td class='state'>AR Rec</td>
                    <td class='state'>AR Sold</td>
                    <td class='state'>CO Rec</td>
                    <td class='state'>CO Sold</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                    <td class='firstCol'>242</td>
                    <td class='records'>75005</td>
                    <td class='deals'>0</td>
                    <td bgcolor='#FF6262' class='cpo'>28,464.40</td>
                    <td class='state'>4716</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>866</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor='#D8D8D8'>
                    <td class='firstCol'>241</td>
                    <td class='records'>72798</td>
                    <td class='deals'>0</td>
                    <td bgcolor='#FF6262' class='cpo'>27,626.84</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                    <td class='firstCol'>240</td>
                    <td class='records'>77212</td>
                    <td class='deals'>0</td>
                    <td bgcolor='#FF6262' class='cpo'>29,301.95</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor='#D8D8D8'>
                    <td class='firstCol'>239</td>
                    <td class='records'>74151</td>
                    <td class='deals'>2</td>
                    <td bgcolor='#FF6262' class='cpo'>14,070.15</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
                    <td class='firstCol'>238</td>
                    <td class='records'>75859</td>
                    <td class='deals'>14</td>
                    <td bgcolor='#FF6262' class='cpo'>2,056.32</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                    <td class='state'>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='firstCol'><b>Totals</b></td>
                    <td><b>375,025</b> </td>
                    <td><b>16</b></td>
                    <td><b>8,895.12</b></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.q4').bind('scroll', fnscroll);
    $('.q2').html($('.q4').html());
    $('.q3').html($('.q4').html());
});

function fnscroll() {
    //alert('*');
    $('.q2').scrollLeft($('.q4').scrollLeft());
    $('.q3').scrollTop($('.q4').scrollTop());
}
```

This is the CSS:

```
body {width:500px;}
.q1, .q2, .q3, .q4 {overflow:hidden; display:block; float:left;}
.q1 {width:48px; height: 47px;}
.q2 {width:450px; height: 47px;}
.q3 {width:48px; height: 100px;}
.q4 {width:452px; height: 116px; overflow:auto;}

.q2 .firstCol, .q3 thead, .q4 thead, .q4 .firstCol {display:none;}
.q2 td {background-color:#D8D8D8;}
.q3 td {background-color:#D8D8D8;}

.container {width:500px;}

table td.state, table td.year {width: 40px; min-width:40px;}
table td.records {width: 57px; min-width:57px;}
table td.deals {width: 40px; min-width:40px;}
table td.cpo {width: 65px; min-width:65px; text-align:right;}
table thead tr td.cpo {width: 65px; min-width:65px; text-align:center;}
```

What am I do wrong for the header and first column not to appear?

Answer (score 0):

This line is hidding it all

```
.q2 .firstCol, .q3 thead, .q4 thead, .q4 .firstCol {display:none;}
```

Check the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/p9PeK/8/

Cheers.

Vitor.

Comment: Yea but then the header and first column are not frozen.  Here is the fiddle from where I got the idea and code: http://jsfiddle.net/9NcnH/

Comment: Ignore the fiddle, just open chrome dev tools, or right click the table, and choose "Inspect Element" and figure by yourself what style is being applied. Everything is there, including the style selected that made it not display!

Comment: Well I figured it out.  The example fiddle I was going off of is using an external resource of jquery.